# PROLOG. Get all objects from list matching a pattern

Tags: prolog

I am a beginner in prolog and i have a problem with getting objects from list matching a pattern.
If i have a list [1,2,3,4,5,1,1] . I want to use a predicate selectAll(Elem,List,X).
Where i use ?- selectAll(1,[1,2,3,4,5,1,1],X), I get X =[1,1,1], but i also want to use data structures inside the predicate, not only atoms.

I originally wrote this predicate for getting all matching elements, but it works only for simple cases, where only atoms are used:

```
selectAll(_, [], []).
selectAll(X, [X | LIST], [X | RES]):-
    selectAll(X, LIST, RES),!.
selectAll(X, [H | LIST], RES):-
    selectAll(X, LIST, RES).
```

When i use this test predicate, everything works fine. I get X=[1,1,1], the result i want.

```
test_select_all:-
    selectAll(1, [1,2,3,4,5,1,1], X),
    write(X),nl,
    fail.
```

I have a data structure called `kv_pairs(A,B)` where A and B contain atoms of any type.
So when i use the selectAll predicate for this datatype, i get unwanted results. X = [kv_pair(1,a)]. It selects only 1 element at most.

```
test_select_all_dict:-
    selectAll(kv_pair(1,_), [kv_pair(1, a), kv_pair(1, b),kv_pair(3, jkak), kv_pair(15, asdjk), kv_pair(1, c)], X),
    write(X),nl,
    fail.
```

I then created this predicate, specifically for finding list elements, where all types are kv_pairs

```
selectAll(_, [], []).
selectAll(kv_pair(Arg, _), [kv_pair(Arg,_) | LIST], [kv_pair(Arg,_) | RES]):-
    selectAll(kv_pair(Arg, _), LIST, RES),!.
selectAll(kv_pair(Arg, X), [kv_pair(A, B) | LIST], RES):-
    selectAll(kv_pair(Arg, X), LIST, RES).
```

But then i get also unwanted results.
`X = [kv_pair(1,_8378),kv_pair(1,_8396),kv_pair(1,_8426)]`
How can i get
`X = [kv_pair(1,a),kv_pair(1,b),kv_pair(1,c)]`?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ISO predicate [subsumes_term/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=subsumes_term/2) to undo bindings after unification:

```
select_all(Pattern, List, Result) :-
    select_all_loop(List, Pattern, Result).

select_all_loop([], _, []).
select_all_loop([X|Xs], P, R) :-
    (   subsumes_term(P, X)
    ->  R = [X|Ys]
    ;   R = Ys ),
    select_all_loop(Xs, P, Ys).
```

Examples:

```
?- select_all(kv_pair(1,_), [kv_pair(1,a), kv_pair(1,b), kv_pair(3,c), kv_pair(4,d), kv_pair(1,c)], R).
R = [kv_pair(1, a), kv_pair(1, b), kv_pair(1, c)].

?- select_all(p(1,Y), [p(1,a), p(1,b), p(2,b), p(1,c)], L).
L = [p(1, a), p(1, b), p(1, c)].

?- select_all(p(X,b), [p(1,a), p(1,b), p(2,b), p(1,c)], L).
L = [p(1, b), p(2, b)].
```